# Avoiding call stack error

Tags: javascript, recursion, callstack

I know what `call stack size exceeded` means but I need a way around it.

I get it when I call this recursive function

```
function fill(x_y) {
    var locColor = getPx(x_y[0], x_y[1]);
    if (locColor != pref.color) {
        setPx(x_y[0], x_y[1], pref.color);
        if (getPx(x_y[0] - 1, x_y[1]) == locColor) {
            fill([x_y[0] - 1, x_y[1]]);
        }
        if (getPx(x_y[0], x_y[1] - 1) == locColor) {
            fill([x_y[0], x_y[1] - 1]);
        }
        if (getPx(x_y[0] + 1, x_y[1]) == locColor) {
            fill([x_y[0] + 1, x_y[1]]);
        }
        if (getPx(x_y[0], x_y[1] + 1) == locColor) {
            fill([x_y[0], x_y[1] + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

It's for a canvas application.

`x_y` is simply x and y coordinates where fill was called.

`setPx` prints a rectangle on the canvas given coordinates.

`getPx` gets the color of a rectangle of the canvas given it's coordinates

`pref.color` is the color that the user has selected for `setPx`

Can this function be done without recursion?

Comment: Yes, I think every recursive function can be rewritten without recursion, although it's not always better. By the way, your code will run indefinately (that is, until the stack overflow) if the color of `getPx(x_y[0], x_y[1])` is the same as `pref.color`.

Comment: BTW. If this is of any use to anyone. The call stack size limit for chrome is 20915. I got that from doing a few tests with a very basic recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fills in order:

- left,
- top,
- right,
- bottom

(unless I got the coordinates system wrong).

You can do a solution without recursion by using a list of `x_y` to process; and instead of using the stack for recursion, you use the list for storing the parameters for your next calls.

```
function fill(x_y) {
    var todo = [x_y];
    var iniColor = getPx(x_y[0], x_y[1]);
    while (todo.length) {
        var curr = todo[0];
        var locColor = getPx(curr[0], curr[1]);
        todo = todo.slice(1);
        if (locColor != iniColor) { continue; }
        if (locColor == pref.color) { continue; }
        setPx(curr[0], curr[1], pref.color);

        todo.push([curr[0]-1,curr[1]  ]);
        todo.push([curr[0],  curr[1]-1]);
        todo.push([curr[0]+1,curr[1]  ]);
        todo.push([curr[0],  curr[1]+1]);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: 2015-03-01

From the comments, this is not as good as the algorithm in the question because of the number of iterations. In this block, I didn't check the condition early, which means they are added to the `todo` list even though they may not be good candidates. And when the point is processed later, the condition is checked.

```
        todo.push([curr[0]-1,curr[1]  ]);
        todo.push([curr[0],  curr[1]-1]);
        todo.push([curr[0]+1,curr[1]  ]);
        todo.push([curr[0],  curr[1]+1]);
```

Solution: check early as in the question; before calling `push`.

Comment: Excellent! I never would have thought of that!

Comment: I've noticed that `numTimesLooped == (x * 2) * ((y * 2) - 1) + 1 /*if called in top left corner*/` but the code in my question `numTimesLooped == x * y /*absolute minimum*/` is there a way to make it more efficient. **Please, don't take this as criticism. I really appreciate your answer.**